# Vertical overflow of table td

Tags: css, html-table, overflow

Is it possible to set overflow hidden or visible for a table td that works in the vertical direction?

http://jsfiddle.net/jkXBH/

Comment: No, you cannot. Yet another reason to [not use tables for layout](http://phrogz.net/CSS/WhyTablesAreBadForLayout.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll have to wrap your td's content into a div and set that div's width and height,  can't hide overflow content.

http://jsfiddle.net/Wx58E/

Comment: That seems to be a good solution, thanks. Also works with overflow-y ... http://jsfiddle.net/Wx58E/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use overflow-y:hidden;

Comment: The area extending to the right is div2, which you define to 200px;

Comment: Yes, #td1 where #div1 is located has the overflow-y, but #div1 (yellow bar) does not grow beyond the td.

Comment: can you provide some more details?